# Hardware Random Number Generator error Arm M4

Tags: c, arm, embedded, microcontroller

I´m new in Arm microcontroller programming. I read the datasheet and found this :

1. Reset/initialize.
2. Write 1 to `CR[INTM]`, `CR[HA]`, and `CR[GO]`
3. Poll `SR[OREG_LVL]` until it is not 0.
4. When `SR[OREG_LVL]` is not 0, read the available random data from
   `OR[RANDOUT]`
5. Repeat steps 3 and 4 as needed.

These are the steps for generating random numbers. Could someone give me a code example ? I'm working with the k64 sub-family, specifically [MK64FX512VLL12](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/K64P144M120SF5RM.pdf).

Here's what I've tried:

```
void Rng_Test() 
{ 
  RNG->CR |= RNG_CR_SLP_MASK; 
  RNG->CR |= RNG_CR_GO_MASK; 
  RNG->CR |= RNG_CR_HA_MASK; 
  RNG->CR |= RNG_CR_INTM_MASK; 
  while (RNG_SR_OREG_LVL_MASK == 0) { } 
}
```

Comment: ARM is a whole family of architectures for microprocessor *cores*. The core itself doesn't have any RNG hardware. It is specific to your particular chip, which you should specify and give a link to a datasheet.

Comment: @Eugene Sh https://www.google.com.ar/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/K64P144M120SF5RM.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwii1YabkcrRAhVHD5AKHcw_Ai4QFgggMAE&usg=AFQjCNG3n8izN9FYRkglnYBFnIbsGBW1jA   MK64FX512VLL12

Comment: What specifically are you having trouble doing?  The steps the datasheet lays out seem rather clear (write some registers, read some others).  What step is causing you the problem?  As the datasheet notes, OREG_LVL is in RNG_SR, at 0x4002_9004...  RNG_OR at 0x4002_900C has RANDOUT...

Comment: Show us your current code and tell us the error you mention in the title, you'll get more help that way.

Comment: I don´t know how to read this field : RNG_OR_RANDOUT(x).  @Colin__s           My current code:                                                    void Rng_Test()
{
RNG->CR |= RNG_CR_SLP_MASK; 
 RNG->CR |= RNG_CR_GO_MASK;
    RNG->CR |= RNG_CR_HA_MASK;
    RNG->CR |= RNG_CR_INTM_MASK;
 
    while (RNG_SR_OREG_LVL_MASK == 0)
{
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the code you already have

```
void Rng_Init() {
    RNG->CR |= RNG_CR_SLP_MASK; 
    RNG->CR |= RNG_CR_GO_MASK; 
    RNG->CR |= RNG_CR_HA_MASK;
    RNG->CR |= RNG_CR_INTM_MASK; 
}

int Rng_GetRand() {
    while ((RNG->SR & RNG_SR_OREG_LVL_MASK) == 0);
    return RNG->OR;
}
```

Something like the above should work, `Rng_Init()` is required once, `Rng_GetRand` should return a new random number (not necessarily different) each time it's called.